# Error with PWA 12.7.0 on Magento 2.4.3

Tags: magento2.4.3, pwa, venia, upward-connector

I installed PWA metapackage as I read it was necessary for PWA versions later than 12.1.0.
But I am still getting error on the PWA frontend i.e.

`Cannot query field "errors" on type "CartItemInterface".`

I think errors dosn't exist on type CartItemInterface, and the metapackage is installed.

Need help here.